# What's the best way to use requestAnimationFrame and fixed frame rates

Tags: javascript, html5, animation

I recently got into using the HTML5-`requestAnimationFrame`-API a lot on animation-heavy websites, especially after seeing the **[Jank Busters](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hAzhayTnhEI)** talk. This seems to work pretty well and really improve performance in many cases.

Yet one question still persists for me: When wanting to use an animation that is *NOT* entirely calculated (think spritesheets for example) you will have to aim for a fixed frame rate. Of course one could go back to use `setInterval` again, but maybe there are other ways to tackle this.

The two ways I could think of using `requestAnimationFrame` with a fixed frame rate are:

```
var fps = 25; //frames per second

function animate(){

   //actual drawing goes here
   setTimeout(function(){
      requestAnimationFrame(animate);
   }, 1000 / fps)

}

animate();
```

or

```
var fps = 25; //frames per second

var lastExecution = new Date().getTime();

function animate(){

    var now = new Date().getTime();

    if ((now - lastExecution) > (1000 / fps)){
        //do actual drawing
        lastExecution = new Date().getTime();
    }

    requestAnimationFrame(animate);

}

animate();
```

Personally, I'd opt for the second option (the first one feels like cheating), yet it seems to be more **[buggy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13191894/safari-on-ipad-wont-stop-requesting-animation-frames)** in certain situations.

Is this approach really worth it (especially at low frame rates like 12.5)? Are there things to be improved? Is there another way to tackle this?

Comment: Not entirely related to the question but still useful: take a look at Date.now().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your animation should be calculated even if that calculation is entirely a function of time. And at any given time you should be able to `draw()` an [animated] image and know that you're getting the right frame. You want something like this, but not necessarily *this*:

```
// whatever your "attributes" looks like, the point is you've given enough
// information to the constructor to find ordered frames in the image and know
// the framerate
function SpriteAnimation(image, attributes) {

  // you probably want a SpriteFrame "class" to populate here, based on whatever
  // existing code you use to extract frames from the sprite
  this.frames = [ SpriteFrame, SpriteFrame, ... ];
                         // ... getFramesFromImageAndAttributes(image, attributes)

  // if the animation is running, this is the time it started
  this.startTime = 0;

  // whatever your framerate is ... 
  this.fps = 25;         // getFPSFromAttributes(frame_attributes)

  // whether the animation loops infinitely
  this.loop = true;      // getLoopFlagFromAttributes(frame_attributes)

  // for canceling the animationframe request, if necessary
  this.animationFrameRequestId = null;

  // draw whichever frame should be visible *right now*
  this.draw = function() {

    // unconditionally show the first frame if the animation isn't running
    if (this.startTime == 0) {
      this.frames[0].draw();
      return;
    }

    // there may be a better and more accurate way to compute this ...
    var frame_duration = 1000 / this.fps;
    var now = (new Date()).getTime();
    var elapsed_time = now - this.startTime;
    var visible_frame = Math.floor(elapsed_time / frame_duration);

    if (visible_frame_number > frames.length) {
      if (!this.loop) {
        // we're past the end of the animation and we're not looping.
        // stop the animation.
        this.startTime = 0;
        visible_frame = 0;
      }
    }

    this.frames[visible_frame % frames.length].draw();

    if (this.startTime != 0) {
      var _t = this;
      requestAnimationFrame(_t.draw);
    }

  }

  this.animate = function() {
    this.startTime = (new Date()).getTime();
    var _t = this;
    requestAnimationFrame(_t.draw);
  }

  this.stop = function() {
    this.startTime = 0;
    if (this.animationFrameRequestId) {
      cancelAnimationFrame(this.animationFrameRequestId);
    }
  }

}

var a = new SpriteAnimation("/path/to/image.jpeg", {
  fps: 25,
  frame_width: 100,
  frame_height: 100,
  image_width: 1000,
  image_height: 10000
});
a.animate();
```

... Or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

For seamless animations, even sprite based use the second option, with `Date.now()`. Dont forget about

> Return value
>
> requestID is a long integer value that uniquely identifies the entry
>   in the callback list. This is a non-zero value, but you may not make
>   any other assumptions about its value. You can pass this value to
>   window.cancelAnimationFrame() to cancel the refresh callback request.

(from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.requestAnimationFrame) )